# Mysql update on duplicate key handling

Tags: mysql

MySQL has syntax `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. But it seems no equivalence for `Update` command. I know `Update IGNORE` syntax but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to have something like `Update .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`?

Comment: What is your intended logic here?  Should an update not go forward, what would be the alternative behavior?

Comment: I want to update email field which is a unique field of the table. In case the new intended email already exists, I'd like to append the primary key (int) to the end of the current email.

Comment: Please add some sample table, before and after, to get the point across.

Comment: In most applications like that, the user is asked what alternate name they want to use, rather than changing the name automatically.

Comment: Anyway, there's nothing built-in to do this, you should do it in your application logic.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar.  On the second thought seem I understand why there is not such an equivalence for the UPDATE command. For example, what happen if the fall back command also cause duplicate key. Then it need another ON DUPLICATE KEY... which seem make no sense.

Comment: If ```Update .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...``` existed, it could cause infinite looping (UPDATE causes ODKU which is UPDATE which causes ODKU which ...).

Answer (score 0):

There is no single SQL statement that does this logic for you.

A workaround is to simply try the simple UPDATE first:

```
UPDATE mytable SET email = ? WHERE ...
```

That may return a duplicate key error because of the change to email results in a conflict on a UNIQUE KEY constraint. You should catch the exception in your code, and then try instead:

```
UPDATE mytable SET email = CONCAT(?, id) WHERE ...
```

It's normal and expected to write application code to do custom logic like this, as an exception handling branch in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be great if the try and catch block can be implemented purely in SQL

Comment: SQL was always designed to be used together with an application programming language.